# Python3 ctypes: How to read an int from a bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm writing a ctypes interface to a 3rd party DLL (I have no control over the DLL).

I've gotten to the point where I can get the DLL function's data (written into a buffer I supply) into a Python bytearray.

How do I convert the bytes in the bytearray into Python integers, strings, etc? I know how to brute-force it - for example (array[0] * 256 + array[1]) but that's dependent on machine endianness and crude.

What's the right way to do this?

The signature of the C function I'm trying to call is:

```
int GetData(int handle, unsigned short id, unsigned char* data, int dataLength, int &actualLength)
```

`data` points to a buffer I supply, `dataLength` is the length of the buffer in bytes.

The DLL function `GetData()` writes into the buffer, and puts the number of bytes it actually wrote into `actualLength`.

It returns an error code as an int (0 means OK).

Here's my code so far - it seems to work as far as it goes:

```
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL("dll_name.dll")

def GetData(handle, option_id):

    BUFSIZE = 6

    buffer = bytearray(BUFSIZE)

    argument = (ctypes.c_char*len(buffer)).from_buffer(buffer)

    actualLength = ctypes.c_int()

    dll.GetData.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_ushort, 
                            ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
    dll.GetData.restype = int

    r = dll.GetData(hCam, option_id, argument, BUFSIZE, ctypes.byref(actualLength))

    if r:
        raise MyError(ERROR_CODES[r])

    return (buffer, actualLength)
```

That returns a buffer that looks like (for example):

```
bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x00\x12\x00\x00')
```

I'm aware that the first two bytes represent a uint16 with the value 257. But how to read that out of the bytesarray in a Pythonic way?

Also, I'm not sure if I'm setting up .argtypes correctly - when should I be using c_char_p, c_void_p, .pointer, and .byref? (Altho, this does seem to work.) I did read the ctype docs, I know they say .byref is faster, but I'm not clear on when .pointer is preferred.

Comment: Due to your code , you didnt assigned anything into buffer?

Comment: @obayhan The DLL function does that.

Comment: in which line? i repeat again there is no assignment to the "buffer" in your code

Comment: @obayhan there is, `buffer = bytearray(BUFSIZE)`. The C function is filling that buffer that you pass in

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga he didnt past in neither buffer nor its pointer into a c function. He just created a Bytearray object, nothing else.

Comment: @obayhan the OP passes `argument = (ctypes.c_char*len(buffer)).from_buffer(buffer)` which shares the underlying buffer with the bytearray object `buffer`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `int.from_bytes`:

```
>>> buffer = bytearray(b'\x01\x01\x00\x12\x00\x00')
>>> int.from_bytes(buffer, 'big')
1103807774720
>>> int.from_bytes(buffer, 'little')
301990145
```

EDIT:

reading over your question carefully, you actually may want to use `struct` to interpret bytes as binary packed data. In this case, if you need to read an unsigned, 16 bit interger,

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack_from('H', buffer)
(257,)
```

Note, it returns a `tuple` to handle more complex, compound formats. [Here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from)

Comment: Oh. Have I got the argtypes right?

Comment: @nerdfever.com `.argtypes` looks ok, `.restype` should be `c_int`.  Also look into `array.array('H',buffer)`.  It takes bytes and converts to an array of the indicated typecode (H is unsigned short).